# What am I missing here?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

That's an idiot question, but I'm missing something here. If $x'= Ax$ and $A$ is linear operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $x'_i = \sum_j a_{ij} x_j$ such that $[A]_{ij} =a_{ij} = \frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j}$, therefore $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} = \sum_j \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x'_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$. However $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sum_j a_{ij} x_j} = \sum_j a_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} =  \sum_j \frac{\partial x'_i}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ !!! What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it in one dimension with $x'=2x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i'} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \sum_j a_{ij} x_j} = \sum_j a_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} $ the $a_{ij}$ somehow climbed from the denominator to the numerator

Comment: The derivative is linear

Comment: @user40276: true, but $\frac d{dkx}=\frac 1k\cdot \frac d{dx}$ where $k$ is a constant by the chain rule.

Comment: Oh!Sorry, I'm sleepy. I forgot that each $x_i$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$. I was thinking that they were vectors.